# Preventing screenshot in robotframework-selenium2

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm using Selenium2Library with robotframework 2.8.3 (python 2.7) when I run all testcases in a single go , there are like 600 images generated (both Passed and Failed test cases) but I don't want screenshot at all or at least not for passed test cases only for failed test cases.

Is that possible by including some keyword or by passing argument in pybot command or someother kind of settings?

something like `$pybot --screenshot stop Testargs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off screenshots on test failure, use the import option `run_on_failure=Nothing` when importing selenium2library.  See [the user guide, "Importing" section](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html).

It shouldn't be taking screenshots on success.  Do you have a default Teardown keyword defined in your top-level package, perhaps?  Check out the results log to see how the screenshot is taken.